Why do some FAA letters of interpretation appear to be removed from the LOI database without any apparent explanation?
I've encountered scenarios over the years in which a person has an old legal interpretation saved somewhere on their computer or a private server on the internet that they whip out during an internet debate about some nuance of the regulations, but when the FAA LOI Database is searched for the letter, it is absent.
Here is a great example:
The August 22, 2006 interpretation in response to K. Kortokrax.
I found that link via  a Google search, and it is indeed even hosted on the faa.gov web domain.
However, when I search the FAA's "Interpretations Search" page, it appears to skip over this letter altogether with no explanation as to why.
I have not heard any rumor that the provisions of this interpretation no longer hold, such as the notion that an instructor and student are not considered to be each other's passenger.
Why do letters of interpretation fall away in this manner?  How can we know the reason? I assume that a letter which is replaced by a newer interpretation would be taken down, but by what process to keep air-missioners up to speed?
One example I know of is the debate sparked by the 2008 Glaser interpretation in which the question was posed -- "May a radar-based approach such a ASR or PAR be used to satisfy one of the 'three kinds of approaches' required on an instrument-rating prerequisite cross-country flight?" -- The response, in an attempt to emphasize the onboard-equipment nature of the navigation equipment to be used, stated that "three kinds of navigation systems" were required.  Some in the community understood this as a misspeaking of the counsel in the context in which the response was intended to be used (as a response to the question about radar approaches only), while others took this new information into unrelated contexts and began touting that one could not use a localizer approach and an ILS on the required flight because they use the same navigation system.
The FAA eventually corrected this debate by issuing a memorandum that directly cancels that interpretation:

That above example is rather pronounced.  What are some other ways the FAA changes stances on LOIs while keeping the public informed?  Do they do "silent redactions" by simply taking the letter down from public view without publicly stating their change in opinion?  Would that explain the disappearance of the 2006 Kortokrax interpretation along with many others?

Voting to close because the question is asking for opinions.

@JuanJimenez nothing here is soliciting opinions.  A person either knows the possible mechanisms of LOI posting and removal, or they don't.  If someone doesn't know, yet they choose to provide a speculative answer, then that answer should be handled appropriately.  By asserting that this question is requesting opinions, you're implying a belief that it cannot be factually-answered, which isn't the case because it most certainly can be by a person with the knowledge of the inner workings of the office of the chief counsel at the FAA.

The only way to get an authoritative answer to this question is to ask the FAA's legal department, and they likely will not give it to you. Everything else is opinion or speculation. My statement stands.

The Kortokrax (2006) letter can still be found on DRS, but its status is listed as "Historical." It's unclear why- I can't find another interpretation rescinding it, and indeed I can find several referencing it. Some letters that have been specifically rescinded also show up in DRS as Historical.

@RyanMortensen Yeah. I guess a lot of flight instructors are gonna have to get night current now!

This doesn't cover the full scope of all possible ways the FAA can inform the public of a rescinded LOI, but it turns out that the day before I posted this question, a formal Memorandum from the FAA was released that informed the public that the 2006 Kortokrax legal interpretation that I used as an example of a "missing" LOI, was indeed rescinded back on July 23, 2023, but the memo informing the public is dated August 16, 2024, nearly 13 months later.
https://www.faa.gov/media/84641

